# The following code is displaying information in the wrong line

Tags: c

Something is wrong with the functionality of the code. As in the screenshot below it's storing the information in the wrong section. More specifically the sex of the employee. It's printing "m" or "f" along with the address of the employee. I think it's something with how the sex function is. Can someone please assist? This is a screenshot of how it displays:

[image]

This is the struct:

```
struct employee
{
        char name[50];
        char sex[7];
        char adrs[50];
        char dsgn[25];
        int age;
        int empID[9];
        float slry;
};
```

Specific code:

```
        printf("\nEnter the sex of the employee (M/m or F/f): ");
        scanf("%6s",e.sex);

        switch(*e.sex)
        {
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                printf("\nMale.\n");
                break;
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                printf("\nFemale.\n  ");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unspecified Sex.");
        }
```

Address code:

```
printf("\nEnter the address of the employee: ");

fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); // ADD THIS TO AVOID SKIP

fgets(e.adrs, sizeof(e.adrs), stdin); // this
```

Entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "struct.h"

void insert();
void list();
void edit();
void del();
void exit();
int tolower();

FILE * fptr, *ftemp;
struct employee e;
long int recsize;
char empname[50];

int main()
{
    int choice;
    fptr = fopen("ems.txt", "r+");


    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't find file! Attempting to create file... \n");

        fptr = fopen("ems.txt","w+");
        if(fptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Can't create file. Exiting...");
         exit(1);
        }
    }

    //Explain the reason for this?
    //recsize = (long int) sizeof(e);//


    while(1)
    {
        printf("*******************************\n");
        printf("\nEmployee management system");
        printf("\n1. Insert employee information");
        printf("\n2. List all employee information");
        printf("\n3. Edit employee information");
        printf("\n4. Delete employee information");
        printf("\n5. Exit");
        printf("\n\n*****************************\n");
        printf("\n\n Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                puts("Insert was chosen");
                insert();

                break;
            case 2:
                puts("List was chosen");
                list();
                break;
            case 3:
                puts("Edit was chosen");
                edit();
                break;
            case 4:
                puts("Delete was chosen");
                del();
                break;
            case 5:
                puts("Exit was chosen");
                exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                puts("Choice is incorrect!!");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


void insert()
{
    char next;

    do
    {
        printf("********************************************************** \n");
        printf("\nEnter the name of the employee: ");
        fgets(e.name, sizeof(e.name), stdin);
        printf("\nEnter the sex of the employee (M/m or F/f): ");
        scanf("%6s",e.sex);

        switch(*e.sex)
        {
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                printf("\nMale.\n");
                break;
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                printf("\nFemale.\n  ");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unspecified Sex.");
        }

        printf("\nEnter the address of the employee: ");

        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); // ADD THIS TO AVOID SKIP

        fgets(e.adrs, sizeof(e.adrs), stdin); // this
        printf("\nEnter designation of the employee: ");
        fgets(e.dsgn, sizeof(e.dsgn), stdin); // this

        printf("\nEnter age of the employee: ");
        scanf("%d", &e.age);
        printf("\nEnter basic salary of the employee: ");
        scanf("%f", &e.slry);
        printf("\nEnter the employee's ID: ");
        scanf("%8d", e.empID);
        fputs(e.name, fptr);
        fputs(e.sex, fptr);
        fputs(e.adrs, fptr);
        fputs(e.dsgn, fptr);
        fprintf(fptr, "%d \n%f \n%d \n", e.age, e.slry, e.empID[9]);
       // fwrite(&e,recsize,1,fptr);
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}
        //fflush(stdin);//
        printf("\nDo you want to input more? (y/n): ");
        next = getche();
        printf("\n");
    }
    while( tolower(next) != 'n' );

    fclose(fptr);
}

void list ()
{
     printf("-------------------------------");
     printf("\nEmployee Details: \n---------------------------------\n");
     rewind(fptr);///moves file to start of the file
     while(fread(&e, recsize, 1, fptr)==1)///read the file and fetch the record one record per fetch
     {
         printf("\n\n%s \t\t%6s \t%s \t%s \t%d \t%.2f \t%d",e.name, e.sex, e.adrs, e.dsgn, e.age, e.slry, e.empID[9]);
     }
     getch();

     /*printf("Name        : %s\n",e.name);
     printf("Address     : %s\n",e.adrs);
     printf("Sex         : %c\n",e.sex);
     printf("Designation : %s\n",e.dsgn);
     printf("Age         : %d\n",e.age);
     printf("Salary      : %.2f\n",e.slry);
     printf("Employee-ID : %d\n",e.empID);*/
}

void edit ()
{
    char next;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the employee's name to be edited: ");
        scanf("%49[^\n]", empname);
        rewind(fptr);
        while(fread(&e, recsize, 1, fptr)==1)///fetch all records from file
        {
            if(strcmp(e.name,empname) == 0) ///if entered name matches with that in file
                printf("\nEnter new name, sex, address, designation, age, salary and employee ID: ");
                scanf("%s%c%s%s%d%f%d", e.name, e.sex, e.adrs, e.dsgn, &e.age, &e.slry, e.empID);
                fseek(fptr, -recsize, SEEK_CUR);/// move cursor 1 step back from current position
                fwrite(&e, recsize,1,fptr); ///override the record
                break;
        }

        printf("\nEdit another record(y/n)");
        next = getche();
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}

    }
    while(next != 'n');

    return ;
}

void del()
{
    char next;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter name of employee to delete: ");
        scanf("%s",empname);
        ftemp = fopen("Temp.dat","wb"); ///create a intermediate file for temporary storage
        rewind(fptr); ///move record to starting of file
        while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fptr) == 1)  ///read all records from file
        {
            if(strcmp(e.name,empname) != 0)  ///if the entered record match
            {
                fwrite(&e,recsize,1,ftemp); ///move all records except the one which is to be deleted to temp file
            }
        }

        fclose(fptr);
        fclose(ftemp);
        remove("ems.txt"); ///remove original file
        rename("Temp.dat","ems.txt"); ///rename temp file to original file name
        fptr = fopen("ems.txt", "rb+");
        printf("Delete another record(y/n)");
        int ch;  while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}
        next = getche();


    }while( tolower(next) != 'n' );
    fclose(fptr);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You can't `fseek()` when `stdin` is connected to a terminal.

Comment: `fgets()` puts the newline in the buffer. Do you really want newlines in your structure?

Comment: Are you reading the data from a file? I suspect the file has CRLF newlines.

Comment: Please don't post text as screenshot, especially since you have it in a text editor already.

Answer (score 0):

After each `fgets()`, add code to lop off the potential trailing `'\n'`

```
fgets(data_array, sizeof data_array, stdin);
data_array[strcspn(data_array, "\n\r")] = '\0';  // add
```

Comment: when I do that all data is grouping in one line

Comment: Change `fputs(data_array, fptr);` to `fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", data_array);`

Comment: @DDArtCustom Tip:  1) Avoid mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` in the same program - use `fgets()`  2)  Avoid `scanf()` until you understand why its bad.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not writing fixed-size records to the file. You do:

```
        fputs(e.name, fptr);
        fputs(e.sex, fptr);
        fputs(e.adrs, fptr);
        fputs(e.dsgn, fptr);
```

`fputs()` just writes each string up to its trailing null byte, not the full declared size of each string. Also, you're not writing the integer members to the file at all.

But when you read the file, you read an entire record

```
     while(fread(&e, recsize, 1, fptr)==1)///read the file and fetch the record one record per fetch
```

That expects each member to be its full size, and also to include the integer members.

You should just write the whole record to the file:

```
fwrite(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fptr);
```

Comment: when I include: fwrite(&e, sizeof(*e), 1, fptr);   , I get this error: invalid type argument of unary '*' have struct employee

Comment: Sorry, should be `sizeof(e)`